# How to indent a block of text in an m4 macro

Tags: macros, m4

Is there a good way to uniformly indent a block of text in an m4 macro?  In other words, the macro

```m4
define(`mytext',dnl
This is
a
piece of text
that I would like
to indent)
mytext
```

generates

```
This is
a
piece of text
that I would like
to indent
```

I'd like to have a way to indent the whole block of text to a specified amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [patsubst](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4//manual/m4-1.4.13/html_node/Patsubst.html#Patsubst):

```
patsubst(mytext,`^', ` ')
```