# include file and indent every line

Tags: m4

I want to include a file and have all the lines indented. I want it to be a code block in a markdown document.

Basically I want something like this:

```
text
include(somefile)
text
```

to have this output:

```
text
    content
    from
    somefile
text
```

I looked through the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html#Patsubst) and found `patsubst`. I also found this question and answer: [How to indent a block of text in an m4 macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026753/how-to-indent-a-block-of-text-in-an-m4-macro)

That works for files containing no commas:

```
$ cat textnocomma 
some text.
with sentences.
and no commas.

$ cat patsubstincludenocomma
text
patsubst(include(textnocomma), `^', `    ')
text

$ m4 patsubstincludenocomma
text
    some text.
    with sentences.
    and no commas.

text
```

But when I `include` a file that contains a comma:

```
$ cat textcomma 
some text.
with sentences.
and, commas.

$ cat patsubstincludecomma
text
patsubst(include(textcomma), `^', `    ')
text

$ m4 patsubstincludecomma
text
m4:patsubstincludecommanoquote:3: Warning: excess arguments to builtin `patsubst' ignored
some text.
with sentences.
and
text
```

The problem seems to be the naive way m4 does macro expansion. The comma from the included text is interpreted as syntax of the `patsubst` macro. The solution (should be) simple: quote the included text.

But if I quote the `include` then just the first line is indented:

```
$ cat patsubstincludecommaquote 
text
patsubst(`include(textcomma)', `^', `    ')
text

$ m4 patsubstincludecommaquote
text
    some text.
with sentences.
and, commas.

text
```

I have tried different combinations of quoting and literal newlines instead of regex newlines. But all I got so far is either the `excess arguments` error message or just the first line indented.

How can I include text with comma, and maybe other m4 syntax, and have it indented in m4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use external commands?

```
esyscmd(`sed "s,^,    ," textcomma')
```

Comment: it seems to be a viable workaround. although it feels kinda silly to use an external tool when a builtin exists which promises this exact functionality. the only problem seems to be the quoting.

Comment: As I see the bultin solutions don't work with included file - I don't know why. Only the first line will be idented (with `divert`, `paste` or `include` too).

Answer (score 4):

i have done some research and can conclude that quoting the `include` makes `patsubst` no longer recognize `^` (beginning of line) in the text apart from the first line. at least on my system.

```
$ m4 --version
m4 (GNU M4) 1.4.18
...
```

observe:

```
$ cat textnocomma 
some text.
with sentences.
and no commas.

$ cat includenocomma 
foo
patsubst(include(textnocomma), `^', `    ')
bar
patsubst(`include(textnocomma)', `^', `    ')
baz

$ m4 includenocomma 
foo
    some text.
    with sentences.
    and no commas.

bar
    some text.
with sentences.
and no commas.

baz
```

this also happens when defining the text as "string literals" instead of `include`:

```
$ cat definestringliterals 
define(`sometext', `first line
second line
third line')dnl
foo
patsubst(sometext, `^', `    ')
bar
patsubst(`sometext', `^', `    ')
baz

$ m4 definestringliterals 
foo
    first line
    second line
    third line
bar
    first line
second line
third line
baz
```

here is a question and answer that supports this observation: [How to match newlines in GNU M4 _properly_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078827/how-to-match-newlines-in-gnu-m4-properly)

strangely this does not happen if putting the string literals directly inside `patsubst`:

```
$ cat patsubststringliterals 
foo
patsubst(first line
second line
third line, `^', `    ')
bar
patsubst(`first line
second line
third line', `^', `    ')
baz

$ m4 patsubststringliterals 
foo
    first line
    second line
    third line
bar
    first line
    second line
    third line
baz
```

using parens to "quote" the text does not have this problem. but now my text has parens around it:

```
$ cat textcomma 
some text.
with sentences.
and, commas.

$ cat includecomma 
foo
patsubst(include(textcomma), `^', `    ')
bar
patsubst(`include(textcomma)', `^', `    ')
baz
patsubst((include(textcomma)), `^', `    ')
qux

$ m4 includecomma 
foo
m4:includecomma:2: Warning: excess arguments to builtin `patsubst' ignored
some text.
with sentences.
and
bar
    some text.
with sentences.
and, commas.

baz
    (some text.
    with sentences.
    and, commas.
    )
qux
```

so i guess this is a bug. if quoting `include` then `patsubst` will no longer recognize `^` apart from the first line. But quoting `include` is necessary to prevent a comma in the text to be interpreted as syntax.

Comment: I noticed similar yesterday.